# Multirow column with wrapped text -- automatic resize

Tags: tables, multirow, resize

I am trying to generate a table that has the following structure:

[image: table example]

The problem are the red Xs - I want the text in the cell to wrap, and the cell height to adjust automatically. I tried using a minipage, adjusting the size, parbox etc. It can't seem to autosize rows and wrap at the same time. The text will always overflow to the next rows once the two multirows are full.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{lscape}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{landscape} 
        \captionsetup{format=plain} 
        \centering 
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c |p{\linewidth}}     
        \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Range of} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ 
        & parameter1 & param 2 & param 3 &  \\ \hline   
        \multirow{2}{*}{1}  &value & value & value & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{minipage}{15cm}pretty long description that wraps over more than two lines pretty long description that wraps over more than two linespretty long description that wraps over more than two linespretty long description that wraps over more than two linespretty long description that wraps over more than two lines\end{minipage}} \\
        & value & value & value & \\ \hline 
        \end{tabular}   
        \captionof{table}{caption caption caption}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example compilable.

Answer (score 2):

`multirow` doesn't automatically extend the spanned rows, so if the spanning entry is larger than the rest of the table you need to add some space by using `\[..]`

[image]

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{lscape}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{landscape} 
        \captionsetup{format=plain} 
        \centering 
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c |p{\linewidth}}     
          \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Range of} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{} \\[10pt] 
                            & parameter1 & param 2 & param 3 &  \\[10pt]
 \hline   
          \multirow{2}{*}{1}  &value & value & value & 

  \multirow{3}{15cm}{pretty long description that
 wraps over more than two lines pretty long description 
that wraps over more than two linespretty long description 
that wraps over more than two linespretty long description 
that wraps over more than two linespretty long description 
that wraps over more than two lines} \\[20pt]


                            & value & value & value & \\[10pt]
 \hline 
        \end{tabular}   
        \captionof{table}{caption caption caption}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```